# How to dismiss keyboard from UIPageViewController's child ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uipageviewcontroller, dismiss

I have a View Controller that has a container that is UIPageViewController and has some child UIViewContorllers.

In the parent view Controller I have a searchBar and I want from child view Controllers to dismiss the keyboard of the parent view controller when tap on table view.

The problem is that if I add a tap gesture recognizer to the container it doesn't detect the tableview did select row delegate function that I need in some of the UIPageViewController child controllers. 
I imagine some ways to do it, with notification, delegates etc.. But is there any way to just dismiss keyboard from anywhere?

Comment: try this method override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can call ( if the embed field is in a subview ):

`self.view.endEditing(force: true)`

or ( it it's not )

`UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.endEditing(true)`

Comment: It doesn't work if it gets called from UIPageViewController child controller and the keyboard opened in the parent of the UIPageViewController ViewContorller

Comment: then call it on the window ^^